# How to share screen without login

Tags: login, screen-sharing

I have three Macs on my LAN. Call them **Mini**, **Ret**, and **Flat**. All three have a user named 'chap', who's an Admin. **Mini** and **Ret** are running the most current version of MacOS 10.13, and **Flat** is running the latest MacOS 10.14. **Mini** and **Ret** are both set to permit screen sharing. **Flat** is my laptop.

(Note: when I say "screen share from A to B", A is local and B is remote.)

I can screen share from Ret to Mini, from Mini to Ret, and from Flat to Mini without being prompted for username/password. When I try to screen share from Flat to Ret, though, I'm always prompted to log in.

Ret and Mini have the same System Preference > Sharing settings for screen sharing. Automatic login of 'chap' is set for all three systems.

Any thoughts why Ret is requesting logins from Flat (and not from Mini)?